# Angular2 this.route.params.map

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 i am lazy loading module and setting up child routes as following

in `module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ProgramsComponent},
    { path: 'create/:id', component: CreateProgramComponent}

];
```

here is link utilizing "create" route

```
<a [routerLink]="['create','123']" class="btn btn-primary">New</a>
```

in the receiver component trying to extract id value as following

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private programService:ProgramService) {

    this.route.params
        .map(params => params['id'])
        .switchMap(id => this.programService.getProgramById(id))
        .subscribe(program => this.model = program);
}
```

I am getting following error, any help is appreciated

```
core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.route.params.map is not a function
TypeError: this.route.params.map is not a function
```

Comment: Try to `import rxjs/add/operator/map` to the file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following two lines:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

RxJs is brought in operator by operator to ensure that you only load what you need.
In your case you are using two operators; `map` and `switchMap`