# Angular 7: params.map is not a function

Tags: angular, npm, angular7

On trying to run my Angular 7 app using `ng serve`, I have suddenly been receiving the following error:

`ERROR in params.map is not a function`

I have no idea where this error is coming from and ng is not giving away too many details.

I have tried reinstalling node, running `npm cache clean --force`. I have also tried reverting to a previous commit, which makes me think it is a problem with npm and not my code.

Anyone seen this before?  A Google search yields only meagre results.

Comment: params is an observable, so you need to use subscribe method. There is one thread similar to your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272258/angular2-this-route-params-map

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately :(

Comment: @serlingpa, I had an error that took me all day yesterday related to this not so clear error message. In my case, the problem was apparently the way I structured my barrel files (index.ts). Take a look and maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55537262/6433166

Answer (score 4):

Now that rxjs has updated, you need to use it in conjunction with `pipe`, as the `Observable` itself no longer has a `map` function. Instead, you should do:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

//...

params.pipe(
  map(() => return true) // Do whatever here
)
```

Comment: Eh? What are you talking about? I haven't used this in my code. There is no `params.pipe`.

Comment: I'm saying you need to use it, because RXJS jas been updated, so the `Observable` no longer has a `.map` function directly.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand your meaning. I am not using `params.map` in my code. The error is occuring right at the end of the build process, followed by `failed to compile`.

Comment: Sorry, I apologise, I didn't realise. It must be coming from one of your dependencies... Have you tried installing `rxjs-compat` as well? https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: I have added that package, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue also appears when using barrels with index.ts, specially if you are using a Library project.
Avoid the use of nested index.ts barrels and export in your public api directly when possible.

from user @user184994

```
export * from './effects'

// instead of:
// import * as SOMETHING from './effects'
// export {SOMETHING};
```

this is a known issue with Angular and nested barrels where webpack or angular compiler fails to map nested index.ts barrels