# Typescript import alias + barrel file

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I spent a lot of time recently because of a particular behavior of something (and I could not identify the possible root cause) in angular/ngrx/typescript ecosystem.

The scenario: I've built up some effects and I have exported them in a barrel file (`index.ts`):

```
import {MyEffects} from './my.effects';

export const effects: any[] = [
  MyEffects,
];
```

Then, in another barrel file, one level up in my directory structure, I have:

```
import * as EFFECTS from './effects'
export {EFFECTS};
```

```
-store
 |-index.ts   <= export {EFFECTS}
 |-effects
   |-index.ts
   |-my.effects.ts
```

And, finally, in the `NgModule`'s imports array:

```
  [
   ...
   EffectsModule.forFeature(EFFECTS.effects),
   ...
  ]
```

When I tried to compile this, I got a way too short error message:

`ERROR in params.map is not a function`

And nothing more. And it prevented my project from compiling. And more... if I run `ng serve` the error also occurred, but if I changed anything while `ng serve` was watching for files changes, it simply recompiled the project successfully.

After an entire day looking for what could possibly be causing it, I figured out that the alias part wasn't doing what I thought it should do. Then, I've changed a little bit the structure and it's now working as expected

### SOLUTION:

In the first barrel file:

```
import {MyEffects} from './my.effects';

export const EFFECTS: any[] = [
  MyEffects,
];
```

In the up-level barrel file:

```
export * from './effects'

// instead of:
// import * as SOMETHING from './effects'
// export {SOMETHING};
```

And in the `NgModel`:

```
  [
   ...
   EffectsModule.forFeature(EFFECTS),
   ...
  ]
```

### But... why???

Am I misunderstanding any part of this process?

I'm not sure if this is important, but the feature that is registering the effects is lazy loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a weird hierarchy.
`export *` and `import/export` don't behave in the same way.

When you use `export *`, TypeScript behaves like all the exported symbols in that file are actually inside the file, even if they were imported from elsewhere. In other words, that module is just a transparent level in the hierarchy and it's only useful for shortening the paths (you will be able to write `import {foo} from './module'` in place of `import {foo} from './module/src/foo`).

Instead, when you use something like:

```
import * as smth from './path';
export {smth}
```

You are introducing a further level that wasn't there before. And it is the `smth` keyword. You won't get rid of the `smth` key, it's there and it's now wrapping your whole module.

Going back to your example, you should edit your question showing how you import `Effects` in your `NgModule`.
If you imported it like:

```
import * as effects from './effects.ts';
```

Then you're introducing again a new symbol that wraps all the variables, so the correct path will be `effects.effects.effects.etc`.

Using destructuring and `export *`, instead, will let you import and export variables without creating wrappers.

The question now is, why didn't the compiler warn you? Because the typescript compiler is usually good at catching these types of problems. The solution is likely here:

```
export const effects: any[] = [
```

Remove the type definition (`any[]`) and let TypeScript interfere the type, I'm pretty sure it will show you the error that you were missing.

Comment: When I first load the project right after `ng serve`, it gives me a warning (not an error) and it doesn't work. If I refresh the page (without stopping the dev server), I get no warnings and everything works fine. It's like the compiler got lost with the double indirection. And I cannot compile for production.